# How to make old keyboard more responsive

Tags: keyboards, hp

Have an old (HP Omnibook from 1993+) keyboard that feels too sluggish. It takes a little bit too much effort to press the buttons. There is no difference between individual buttons. This particular machine was like this when I got it, but I have used other ones that had better keyboards.

[image]

(It feels like there is some additional resistance beyond the rubber springs, so the springs themselves are probably fine.)

Am wondering if it would be a good idea to add some lubrication (silicone), or if that would degrade the rubber (or cause some other problem)? Any other advice?

Also, are those rubber springs generally available for purchase?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a feature, not a bug. Many keyboard manufacturers have models with a bigger resistance (you have to press it with a slightly bigger force). Some people with "heavy fingers" appreciate it.

The "small rubber things" are the "cheap springs" alternative. Those give the resistance against pushing and provides the proper reaction to pushing (force and tactile feeling of "press"). You can replace those rings with some more "soften" to get the desired effect.

I don't know it's available now. Try search "keyboard replacement rubber spring". Maybe the easiest way is to find some broken keyboard with the same mechanism and try to salvage them.

Comment: If  the product number is readable on the keyboard, I would contact HP directly. They might be able to help, but they might not want to help...